# handling login logout on receiving fcm

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an app which receives a push notification from firebase,checks login logout flags true or false and then redirects to login activity or the specified activity accordingly.The flags are working fine without fcm but when an fcm message is recieved and the app s not running ut redirects to login page even if I am already logged in.CLICK_ACTION is a hard coded intent filter which redircts to a specified activity.I am posting my code here.Please help me

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

Handler mHandler;
Intent i;



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
//changes for notification on 9/11/2017
//        if(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()!=null) {
       // Log.e(TAG, "Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //}
    //showNotificationMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
 //        String click_action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
   // Intent i=new Intent(click_action);
 ////////////////////////////////////////
    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AllCallsData Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            Handler mHandler;
            //mHandler = new Handler() {
                handleDataMessage(json);
            //};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        //Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.);
        //Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        //r.play();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

    private void handleDataMessage (JSONObject json){

        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            //JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("senderinfo");
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            //String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");

           JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");
            Common.SESSION_ID = payload.getString("session_id");
            Common.API_KEY = payload.getString("api_key");
            Common.TOKEN = payload.getString("token_id");

             /*OpenTokConfig.SESSION_ID = data.getString("session_id");
            OpenTokConfig.API_KEY = data.getString("api_key");
            OpenTokConfig.TOKEN = data.getString("token_id");*/

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);

            //Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            //Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);
            if(Common.FLAG_LOGGED_IN) {
                i = new Intent(Config.CLICK_ACTION);
            }
            else
            {
                i = new Intent(Config.CLICK_ACTION_LOGIN);
                //Common.LOGIN_CALLRECD=true;
            }
            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, i);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                Common.call_recvd = true;
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
           /* if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }*/
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
   // intent.setAction(Config.CLICK_ACTION);
   // sendBroadcast(intent);


    //startActivity(intent);
    //sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

Comment: When is Common.FLAG_LOGGED_IN initalized?

Comment: the flag is initalized when the user successfully logs in.the value changes from false to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a boolean in SharedPreference indicating whether user is logged in or not, then write a method in MyFirebaseMessagingService which will check that boolean.

```
//--[When User log in is successful]--

private void saveLogin() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferences =  context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    preferences.putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true);
    preferences.commit();
}


//--[In notification service]--
private boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences preferences =  this.getSharedPreferences("SHARE_PREF",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    isLoggedin=preferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);
    return isLoggedin;
}
```

Use saveLogin method to store whether user is successfully logged in or not and use isUserLoggedIn method to get value of that boolean.

Comment: I have already done that.I am using a Common class and storing a boolean there.U can see I am checking in MyFirebaseMessagingService if Common.FLAG_LOGGED_IN is true or false.It works if app is running and I am logged in but when app is not running it redirects to login even if I am logged in

Comment: That's what I am trying to explain. When app is not running, who'll set Common.FLAG_LOGGED_IN flag.

Comment: its working without push notification.When I am logged in and close the app and then I open it again the Flag is set because it is a static flag in final class Common.now where do i set the flag again on receiving push notification?

Comment: Instead of setting flag, try storing boolean in sharedpreferences. So that now you can access this boolean from sharedpreferences in your service.

Comment: i put a string and set value as yes and no on login and logout respectively in shared  preferences now it is not even setting the value even when the app is runninng.sorry

Comment: it wasnt working so I deleted but it was working fine as far as normal login logout sessions are concerned.But with fcm the value wasnt being set even if the app was running.What I feel is that be in Common class or shared pref something needs to be added in onMessageReceived() method when app isnt running.pls check the above code once again and let me know

Comment: I want to ask something.I understood in LoginActivity I will save the boolean as true and then in notification service I have to fetch it whether true or false and redirect accordingly but in your code in the method isUserLoggedin() instead of fetching the current value of boolean it is setting it to false.How will that work?

Comment: No, it is not setting false. See here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: I want to check if user is logged in after setting it true or false now if I check by your code if(isUserLoggedIn()) the code will enter the method and return the return value ie...return preferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);I want to check the value that is present at the tme of checking than returning false